# Large UI on 4k Resolution

Tags: display, mac-pro, resolution

I am using a Mac pro with MacOS Sierra 10.12.4
When using a Wacom Cintiq Pro 16 at 4k, the UI scale gets really large.

[image: Screenshot at 4k resolution]

On 2k the ui looks as it should.

[image: Screenshot at 2k resolution]

Is there any reason why the UI would become that large at 4k? 
It's not possible to properly work like that.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try **System Preferences > Displays > Resolution: Scaled** and then selecting one of the options? That should be the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Yes I tried that. The setting is fully to the right at "More Space". Even with that setting the UI is upscaled like shown in the first picture.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBook Pro early 2013 so I have to drive my Cintiq Pro 16 at 2k.

I think on 4k, Mac OS knows scales UI bigger, because otherwise it would be too small (imagine those 2k Interface Elements at about half the size).

Its probably an issue with the Wacom Driver, that makes it impossible to scale the Interface at 2k.

[image: Wacom Cintiq Pro 16 Display Settings on MacBook Pro early 2013]

Do you have scaling options for the Cintiq on 4k? If you do, its probably a Wacom Driver issue.

I recommend to post a topic on the official Wacom Forum. The Wacom Staff answers really fast.
http://forum.wacom.eu (Wacom Forum Europe)